# Set all nonzero matrix elements to 1 (while keeping the others 0)

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a mesh grid defined as

```
[X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(-100:100, -100:100, 25); % z will have more values later
```

and two shapes (ovals, in this case):

```
x_offset_1 = 40;
x_offset_2 = -x_offset_1;
o1 = ((X-x_offset_1).^2./(2*Z).^2+Y.^2./Z.^2 <= 1);
o2 = ((X-x_offset_2).^2./(2*Z).^2+Y.^2./Z.^2 <= 1);
```

Now, I want to find all points that are nonzero in *either* oval. I tried

```
union = o1+o2;
```

but since I simply add them, the overlapping region will have a value of 2 instead of the desired 1.

How can I set *all* nonzero entries in the matrix to 1, regardless of their previous value?

(I tried `normalized_union = union./union;`, but then I end up with `NaN` in all 0 elements because I'm dividing by zero...)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simplest solution: `A=A~=0;`, where `A` is your matrix.

This just performs a logical operation that checks if each element is zero. So it returns `1` if the element is non-zero and `0` if it is zero.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! You were so fast, SO won't let me mark your answer as accepted until in another 6 minutes :P

Comment: This changes my matrix from a double to a logical

Answer (score 6):

First suggestion: don't use `union` as a variable name, since that will shadow the built-in function [`union`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/union.html). I'd suggest using the variable name `inEitherOval` instead since it's more descriptive...

Now, one option you have is to do something like what [abcd suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5226582/52738) in which you add your matrices `o1` and `o2` and use the [relational not equal to operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ne.html):

```
inEitherOval = (o1+o2) ~= 0;
```

A couple of other possibilities in the same vein use the logical [`not`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/not.html) operator or the function [`logical`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logical.html):

```
inEitherOval = ~~(o1+o2);       % Double negation
inEitherOval = logical(o1+o2);  % Convert to logical type
```

However, the most succinct solution is to apply the logical [`or`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/or.html) operator directly to `o1` and `o2`:

```
inEitherOval = o1|o2;
```

Which will result in a value of 1 where either matrix is non-zero and zero otherwise.

Comment: `union` was just something I came up with in this question - in my actual code I have variable name that correspond to what the ovals represent, so there it's not a problem. Thanks for all the good suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

There is another simple solution, A=logical(A)